# Tcl_Eval to return call stacks when error

Tags: c++, tcl, tcl-api

When using Tcl C++ API **Tcl_Eval**, if it returns **TCL_ERROR**, the error message can be retrieved from `Tcl_GetStringResult(interp)`. However, when executing a bunch of tcl script, the error message doesn't indicate which line the script fails.

Eg:

```
can't find package foobar
    while executing
"package require foobar"
    (file "./test.tn" line 5)
```

`Tcl_GetStringResult(interp)` doesn't provide this information: `(file "./test.tn" line 5)`. Is there a way to print out the call stack like in tcl interpreter so that I know which line the script fails?

Comment: Could `Tcl_GetErrorLine` be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Tony: That would just return the `5` from the above message (well, maybe; it's very context-dependent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are looking for, the error info (i.e., stack trace), is in the global `errorInfo` variable. This information may be retrieved with [`Tcl_GetVar`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/SetVar.htm) or one of its related functions. One of the best to choose is `Tcl_GetVar2Ex` (the name being a product of a slowly evolving API) which is highly efficient:

```
Tcl_Obj *infoObj = Tcl_GetVar2Ex(interp, "errorInfo", NULL, TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);
```

Then you use `Tcl_GetString` to extract the human-readable part as a `char *` (treat as `const`).

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to pull back and report on the errorinfo that is available from the interpreter.

```
Tcl_Obj *top_interpInfoName ;
Tcl_Obj *top_interpInfo ;

top_interpInfoName = Tcl_NewStringObj("errorInfo", -1) ;
    Tcl_IncrRefCount(top_interpInfoName) ;
    top_interpInfo =  Tcl_ObjGetVar2(tcl_interp,
                                     top_interpInfoName,
                                     NULL,
                                     TCL_LEAVE_ERR_MSG) ;
    Tcl_IncrRefCount(top_interpInfo) ;
    ERR_REP2("ERROR: %s", Tcl_GetString(top_interpInfo)) ;
    Tcl_DecrRefCount(top_interpInfoName) ;
    Tcl_DecrRefCount(top_interpInfo) ;
```

ERR_REP2 is my error reporting macro you need to replace it with your own.